# futureBuilder can not get data from snapshot

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

```
 Future fetchData() async{
              List<Profile> list=[];
              list = await Firestore.instance
              .collection("users").getDocuments().then((querySnapshot){
               querySnapshot.documents.forEach((document) {
               list.add( Profile(
                    photos: [document['photoUrl'],],
                    name: document['nickname'],
                    age: 2,
                    distance: 2,
                    education: '3',
                    bio:"a"
                ));

            });
            print(list);
            print('list');
            return list; //[Instance of 'Profile']
        });
}



class _MainControllerState extends State<MainController> {







@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 60.0, 0.0, 30.0),
    child: FutureBuilder(
      future: fetchData(),
      builder: (
        BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot snapshot,
      ){
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done ) {
           if (snapshot.data == null) {
             print(snapshot);//AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>(ConnectionState.done, null, null)
        return Text('no data');

      } else {
         print('matches');
              print(snapshot);
             List<Match> matches = snapshot.data
              .map((Profile profile) => Match(profile: profile))
              .toList();

          return CardStack(
            matchEngine: MatchEngine(matches: matches),
          );
      }

        } else if (snapshot.error) {
          print('matches1');
        } else {
          print('matches2');
        }
        return CardStack();
      },

    ),

  );
}

}
```

when I print out the list , I can get [Instance of 'Profile'],but when I print data in snapshot, I can only get AsyncSnapshot(ConnectionState.done, null, null) , how can I fix that error?

I 've tried to change snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done to snapshot.has data. but it dose not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FutureBuilder` Doesn't know what are you returning from `fetchData()`, so you have to specify that you will be returning a `List<Profile>`. As  `Future` without a type is same as `Future<void>` .

replace:

```
Future fetchData() async{...}
```

with:

```
Future<List<Profile>> fetchData() async{...}
```

Similarly sepecify that in `FutureBuilder`

Instead of:

```
builder: (
    BuildContext context,
    AsyncSnapshot snapshot,
  ){...}
```

Do this:

```
builder: (
    BuildContext context,
    AsyncSnapshot<List<Profile>> snapshot,
  ){...}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried , but it also return AsyncSnapshot<List<Profile>>(ConnectionState.done, null, null)

Comment: @ZivCheung you must be returning null from fetch data. as i have tested the above code, it should work fine.

Comment: @ZivCheung Copy code from https://gist.github.com/jujuo0o/e90d1f36dddd5945db1c5d98b261ac3a and run it in https://dartpad.dev/flutter

Comment: I tried your code ,but it still return flutter: [Instance of 'Profile', Instance of 'Profile']
flutter: list
flutter: AsyncSnapshot<List<Profile>>(ConnectionState.done, null, null)

Comment: @ZivCheung have you tested it in dartpad?

Comment: when I test it in dartpad , runs perfectly

Comment: but when I run in my project , it return null

Comment: @ZivCheung Move your `fetchData` method to `_MainControllerState` class

Comment: it still returns null

Comment: Future<List<Profile>> fetchData()
package:flutter_chat_demo/src/scenes/in/main_controller.dart

This function has a return type of 'Future<List<Profile>>', but doesn't end with a return statement.
Try adding a return statement, or changing the return type to 'void'.

Comment: is it the problem?

Comment: I just solved it by   print(list);
            print('list');
            return list; //[Instance of 'Profile']
        });

            return list; //[Instance of 'Profile']

Answer (score 0):

```
 Future<List<Profile>> fetchData() async{
          List<Profile> list=[];
          list = await Firestore.instance
          .collection("users").getDocuments().then((querySnapshot)  async {
           querySnapshot.documents.forEach((document) {
           list.add( Profile(
                photos: [document['photoUrl'],],
                name: document['nickname'],
                age: 2,
                distance: 2,
                education: '3',
                bio:"a"
            ));

        });

        print(list);
        print('list');
        return list; //[Instance of 'Profile']
    });

        return list; //[Instance of 'Profile']
        }
```